# jQuery.ajax, I always have to request twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am binding the click function `foo` to the anchor tag in `jquery.ajax`. The problem I am facing is that I have to request twice or click the anchor tag twice to make the request. Also I have noticed in the browser under the network bar that ajax request is not triggered, first time when I hit the anchor tag. But when I hit it twice then I see two ajax request in the network tab. I have no idea what is going on?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

function show(thelink)
{

    var cat = thelink.innerHTML;
    var productContainer = document.getElementById("productContainer");

    $.ajax({

           type:"POST",
           url:"fetchdata1",
           data:"cat="+cat,

         success:function(data){
            productContainer.innerHTML ="";
            var $productContainer = $('#productContainer');
            $.each(data,function(key,value){
              if(value['newVar'] === 1)
              {
              $productContainer.append("<div id='productBox' class='grid_3'>\n\
             <a href='product.jsp?id="+value['id']+"'><img src='"+value["image"]+"'/></a><br/>\n\
             <a href='product.jsp?id="+value['id']+"'><span class='black'>"+value['name']+"</span></a><br/>\n\
             <span class='black'>By "+value['company']+"</span><br/><span class='red'>RS."+value['price']+"</span>\n\
             <br/><br/><a href='#' class='remove' onclick='foo(this)' pid='"+value['id']+"'>REMOVE</a></div>");

             }  
             else{

             $productContainer.append("<div id='productBox' class='grid_3'>\n\
             <a href='product.jsp?id="+value['id']+"'><img src='"+value["image"]+"'/></a><br/>\n\
             <a href='product.jsp?id="+value['id']+"'><span class='black'>"+value['name']+"</span></a><br/>\n\
             <span class='black'>By "+value['company']+"</span><br/><span class='red'>RS."+value['price']+"</span></div>"); 
             }
        }) ;

     }      

    });

    return false;
}


  function foo(obj){

            var pid = $(obj).attr("pid");
            $(obj).bind("click", function(){    
                    $.ajax({   
                      type:"POST",
                      url:"removeFromWishlist",
                      data:"pid="+pid,

                      success:function(response){
                        console.log("sent ajax request");
                      }
                    });               
            });

    }
```

Comment: it will be nice if you keep it inside a document ready function https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: makes no sense binding a jQuery click handler to element inside an `onclick` handler. That's why you have to click twice but second clcik will bind a new jquery listener also

Comment: @KishanKumar you can't put `foo()` inside ready...it won't be available in global space that onclick occurs

Comment: @charlietfl so what I should do?

Comment: Use classes on elements and use event delegation and stop using inline javascript

Answer (score 0):

You were binding an extra `onclick` handler to `.remove`.

When working with callbacks on dynamically added elements, its better to bind all required events on `document` context using `$(document).on("click", 'selector', function(){ ... });`.

So instead of `a href='#' class='remove' onclick='foo(this)' pid='"+` do this (see below snippet)

```
$(document).on("click", '#productBox .remove', function(){
    // your ajax call
    $.ajax({   
        type:"POST",
        url:"removeFromWishlist",
        data:"pid="+pid,
        success:function(response){
            console.log("sent ajax request");
        }
    });
});
```

This will separate your HTML layout and its behaviour.

**Below things must be avoided** (Thanks to @charlietfl):

1. Binding 'click' listeners twice on same element.
2. Using javascript inline with your html code.
3. Directly binding a javascript function using `onclick` attribute.
4. Not using javascript unobtrusively.

Hope it helps.

Comment: doesn't explain why, nor make suggestion to get away from using inline script in favor of unobtrusive script. This is 2017 not 1997

Comment: I think I have to bind it because the html which I am creating in jQuery.Ajax wont recognise the onclick function because it is dynamic html.

Comment: @charlietfl, of course, i would have suggested if it was asked. I've just pointed out where the existing script might be wrong

Comment: OP is clearly **trying** to use unobtrusive approach....but you are telling them not to. Is that how you would code this yourself?

Comment: @charlietfl i usually bind events using `$(document).on("click", func...)}` on dynamic elements, and yes i avoid using onclick inline with elements

Comment: @charlietfl i could have posted a better answer (with suggestions) than what is posted now

Comment: so why wouldn't you?

Comment: @charlietfl done it now. feel free to point out things where i might be wrong

Comment: much better and in keeping with modern practices

Comment: @charlietfl, though the comment section is not meant for thanking, thanks for pointing out some important things :)